# Summary Links WP with Variations. Error with "internal" links

Tags: 2013, web-part, variations

I have a site collection that contains two variation labels (sv-se and en-us). The english site is source and the swedish site is a target.

I'll use the standard ootb web part "summary links" on the source site. If I add "external" links, ie www,faceb00k,com the swedish target site also gets the links with no error.

But if I use "internal" links, links that points on sites/pages in the same site collection, the swedish page crashing.

I'll get the error message:

```
List does not exist.
The page you selected contains a list that does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user? <nativehr>0x81020026</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack>

Exception Details: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: List does not exist.
```

Why do I get this error? Why only on internal links? A standard ootb web part and variations, it should work!

Answer (score 1):

The summary links web part and variations had problem, with internal links got broken on destination labels. [December 2013 CU](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;2850024) has apparently fixed the issue.